# How does a function in Qt accept passed arguments from two places?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to wirte a funtion CH1_Hard_Soft to process data, which accepts two arguments from two different function.

```
   double MainWindow::getdata_CH1(double time)
   {
        ...

        double CH1_data=0;
        switch (CH1.Source) {
        case 0:    //software-hard
        CH1_data = CH1_Hard_Soft(time);
        ....
   }
```

The function CH1_Hard_Soft need to accept an argument time from getdata_CH1 and accept a QVector from other thread. And the function CH1_Hard_Soft will process these data and then return a QVector to getdata_CH1(double time). I don't know how to do this. Please give me some suggestions on how to do this.THANKS!!!

Comment: Can you give more details on how all these functions are calling themselves between threads? It's not very clear in your description. You can define functions that process different type of arguments in c++. This is called overloading a function, one type of polymorphism in c++. And if your functions work only on local variables (no globals or shared variables) then they are threadsafe and can be called securely between threads without the need for synchronization.

Comment: Do I understand correctly?: For the result both inputs have to be provided(time and QVector)? And the result will only be returned, if we call it with time? In this case it sounds like you do not have a simple function, but a statefull one (the call with a QVector from the other thread will change the state of the function). You could this setting, by making CH1_Hard_Soft an class that has two member functions. One for accepting QVectors one for processing and returning the values, when provided the time. You will have to think about multithreading and racecondition, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Function Object: create a new class with two attributes (one per parameter). Create setter for each parameter (or redefine the operator `()` to be closer to the behavior of a real function).

Each setter should check if the others are setted also. In that case, call you algorithm and send the result with a signal.

For example:

A simple worker executed in another thread. It will send fake data after 3 seconds

```
class Worker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(): QObject()
    {
    }

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent* ev)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
        emit getVector(QVector<int>() << 2 << 4 << 6 << 8);
        killTimer(timerId);
    }
public slots:
    void run()
    {
        timerId = startTimer(3000);
    }
signals:
    void getVector(QVector<int> const& vec);
private:
    int timerId;
};
```

The Function Object: it will accept two param (a double and a vector)

```
// For convenience. Define a value and a flag to check if the value is well set
template<typename T> struct Param
{
    T value;
    bool isInit;
    Param(): isInit(false)
    {}
    void setValue(T const& v)
    {
        value = v;
        isInit = true;
    }
};


// The processor
class Processor: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Processor(QObject* parent=nullptr): QObject(parent)
    {}

    void operator()(QVector<int> const& vector)
    {
        values.setValue(vector);
        if (time.isInit)
            process();
    }

    void operator()(double t)
    {
        time.setValue(t);
        if (values.isInit)
            process();
    }
signals:
    void done(double result);
private:

    // Will be called as soon as all the parameters are set
    void process()
    {
        // DO something
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
        emit done(time.value * values.value.length());
    }
    Param<QVector<int> > values;
    Param<double> time;
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Run the thread
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    QThread* th = new QThread();
    worker->moveToThread(th);
    QObject::connect(th, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::run);

    Processor CH1_Hard_Soft;

    // Will be called when the CH1_Hard_Soft will send its result
    QObject::connect(&CH1_Hard_Soft, &Processor::done, [=](double result) { qDebug() << "RESULT" << result; });

    // Set the param vector
    QObject::connect(worker, &Worker::getVector, [&](QVector<int> const& vec) { CH1_Hard_Soft(vec); });

    // Call CH1_Hard_Soft with the first param
    double time = 12.6;
    CH1_Hard_Soft(time);


    th->start();

    return app.exec();
```